# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

Could anyone can explain me what this .htaccess code doing?

```
 RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/([^t]{1}[A-Za-z0-9_-]{0,})\.([^s]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]+)$ ../items/go.php?u=$1/$2.$3
```

I have a folder : *mywebsite.com/download/folder1/* with a .htaccess file in the uplevel *mywebsite.com/download/* folder contains code above.

When I access a file directly to the path *mywebsite.com/download/folder1/file.mp4* it returns error :

> mywebsite.com redirected you too many times. Try clearing your
>   cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I tried to clear my browser cookies but the issue persist.
This issue is solved when I commented out the htaccess line above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule appears to be looking for a specific pattern consisting of:

```
<numbers>/<alphanumeric string not starting with t and with other conditions applied>.<alphanumeric string not starting with s>
```

then redirecting the user's browser to go.php with the parsed filename passed as file arguments.

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS is likely due to an infinite redirect loop.  Without knowing what other RewriteRule statements are present it is difficult to narrow down an exact cause.  You can narrow it down further on your end by seeing if the rewritten output might match any other RewriteRule conditions.

In general, the rule looks suspicious for the example input given.  If this is home-grown I would suggest rewriting it entirely, as its current form will given unexpected outputs for user-generated data that could cause any security holes present in the go.php script to be easily exploited / exposed.